# jQuery selector from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass `jQuery` selector from one function to another? 
Does it work like passing variables from one function to another?

i.e:

```js
function hasSelector(){
  var items = $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  return items;
}

function useSelector(){
  //var items = $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  //items.on('click'...);
  
  hasSelector().on('click', function(){
    alert(items);
  )};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** Thanks to some clarifications in comments I've decided to change `hasSelector()` into `object` (I had to pass parameter aswell which i forgot to mention here. Nonetheless I've still used a function.)

```js
var hasSelector = {
  items : function(){
    return $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  }
}

function useSelector(){ 
  hasSelector.items().on('click', function(){
    alert(hasSelector.items(this));
  });
}

useSelector();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item1">Item 1</div>
<div id="item2">Item 2</div>
<div id="item3">Item 3</div>
//returning [obj Obj] since I'm calling on all 3 items at once.
```

Comment: You're returning a jQuery object, not a selector, and naturally passing and returning works just like anything else in the language. You're just missing a closing `'` after `click`.

Comment: Now that you corrected the missing quote, is there some issue you're experiencing that prompted this question? Were you hoping the `items` variable would magically appear at the call site? Are you really just trying to get a reference to the item clicked? What is the *actual* problem?

Comment: items is not defined in the click.

Comment: `items` won't be defined as it's only defined inside `hasSelector`.  Instead of `alert(items)` use `alert(this)` to get the item being clicked or `alert(hasSelector())` to reget the items.

Comment: As an aside: "hasSelector" is not a representative name as that named implies a test "has [item got] selector".  Maybe rename to "getItems" or similar?

Comment: @freedomn-m Well, yes, but then how could I connect `hasSelector` with jQuery function like `.on`, `.hide` etc? Is it like, I have to make `$.fn.hasSelector = function()..`?

Comment: Your .on function call has improperly balanced braces. At the end, curly goes before parenthesis.

Comment: Exactly the way you have with `.on` - `hasSelector().on(...`  `hasSelector().hide()`

Comment: @nehel: Maybe you could ask about the actual problem instead of tiptoeing around it.

Comment: @squint The problem is I want to get `items` from `hasSelector()` inside `useSelector`.

Comment: OK, but it seems like you already know how to assign a return value to a variable. `var items = ...` And there's some specific use that you're hinting at, but not explaining.

Comment: "get items inside useSelector" - nothing to do with jquery, it's to do with variable scope.  Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. Appreciate the answers, they helped me a lot in finding a solution x).

Answer (score 0):

you have closed function by wrong symboles  `)};` correct one is  `});`

```js
function hasSelector(){
  var items = $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  return items;
}

function useSelector(){
  //var items = $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  //items.on('click'...);
  hasSelector().on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).html());
  });
}
                                 
useSelector();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item1">item1</div>
<div id="item2">item2</div>
<div id="item3">item3</div>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question: *How can I pass jQuery selector from one function to another?*   This would answer "why doesn't my code work"

Comment: Most likely just another typo in a hastily prepared code example.

Answer (score 0):

Since your hasSelector function returns a jQuery object, you could use that.

```
function hasSelector() {
  var items = $('#item1, #item2, #item3');
  return items;
}

function useSelector(items) {
  items.on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
  });
}

useSelector(hasSelector());
```